# Google Charts API Chart Request Too Large

Tags: google-visualization

I am attempting to plot a chart thats about 7000 characters with the Google Charts API but the URL will only accept 2000 characters. However I have read that a POST request can support up to 16k characters so I am trying to use that to render the chart. There's a PHP example of how to render the graph and then use that php file as the img src, however how do I pass my dataload to this other page?

If I put it as a GET parameter in the img src itself it will be too many characters again. I've read that you should never make a URL bigger than 2000 characters if you can help it,

Maybe I could output it to a file and then have the img php file have it pull it in each time it's requested?

If anybody has any suggestions, it would be a huge help,

Thanks!

I have read that the URL character-limit depends on the browser, IE is about 2000, does this mean that an img src with a bigger character count than this will not render properly in this browser? Alternatively FF has a much bigger limit, the following website says more than 100,000 so would it render in FF?

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just reacquired the dataload with a seperate request and then used the php file as an image source.

Answer (score 0):

Use curl to convert the 'GET' request to my proxy script into a 'POST' request to google.
Then you can just substitute your proxy url for googles in your app.

```
function getChartProxy()
{
    if(isset($_GET) && count($_GET)){
       ob_clean();//remove any header or error messages from the output buffer
       //example for testing
       // $url = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chs=250x100&chd=t:40,30,20&chl=Hispanic|NonHispanic|Incomplete";

       $getData = http_build_query($_GET);
       $url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart';         
       $ch = curl_init();

       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$getData);
       ob_start();

       curl_exec ($ch);
       curl_close ($ch);
       $bytes = ob_get_contents();

       ob_end_clean();    
       header('Content-type: image/png');
       echo $bytes;
    }
}
```

This thing is a proxy so it need some kind of access control to be used in production.